# bypassing application controls from database

Tags: oracle-12c, audit

I'm currently doing an audit on oracle payables & CC&B and I noticed that the DBA team has full access on the database and with no audit trail enabled.

Is it possible to bypass the application controls by modifying the values in the database, values like the amount, account id and etc with this type of access to the database?

Comment: Most probably, unless there are triggers to stop it.

Comment: even if triggers existed, in most cases the DBAs could also disable any such triggers or audits, make changes to data, then turn the triggers and audits back on. it is important to audit not only the data, but changes to database objects like that as well.